# Extract Dataframe name from read_csv

Tags: python, string

Hundreds of csv's are in my single python file, and each lead into their own plot.

Each plot's title is a function of the Dataframe's filename.

Is it possible to put the plot title equal to the Dataframe's file name?

Comment: I would store all of the data frames and file names in a list of dictionaries and structure the plotting around that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.